# Fade in and out images on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Curious to see how I could expand this to work with more than two images.

```js
const one = document.getElementById('one')
const cover = document.getElementById('cover')
const filling = document.getElementById('filling')

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    let scrollPosition = window.scrollY
    let bottomHeight = window.innerHeight

    if (scrollPosition / bottomHeight <= 1){
        one.style.opacity = 1 - (scrollPosition / bottomHeight)
        cover.style.position = 'fixed'
        filling.style.display = 'none'
    }
    else{
        cover.style.position = null
        filling.style.display = 'block'
    }
})
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  height: 3500px;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#filling{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#cover{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#cover > div{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#one{
  z-index: 2;
}

#two{
  z-index: 1;
}

#three{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="filling" style="display: none"></div>

<div id="cover" style="position: fixed">
  <div id="one">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200/1000/1000" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="two">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/1000/1000" alt="">
  </div>

  <div id="three">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/202/1000/1000" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

I would like to expand to three images that would change opacity and give the effect of them fading in but when adding a third one under #cover it only displays the first image. Here's the working code that I found in another solution. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. Please edit your code to include a 3rd image so we can see it not working. Currently your code shows two images and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for that @ChrisBarr! I edited the code to include the 3rd photo and it still works but only displays photo #1 and #3 when I run it now.

Comment: So what exactly are you wanting here?  And you scroll it fades out `one` to then show `two`, keep scrolling so `two` fades out to show `three`?  Or something else?  What have you tried so far because I see that the code doesn't even attempt to do anything with an image besides the first one.

Comment: Correct, so when we scroll to that section it stays in the fixed position and goes through image one > fade out to show two >  fade out to show three and then resume scrolling to the rest of the page.